# Creating dll from cpp files with nmake

Tags: c++, dll, nmake

There is a problem: i need to compile the dll from all source *.cpp files in a particular folder with a help of nmake.
For example, cpp files stored in the folder ".\src", and they must be compiled into one dll.

Where i can read about nmake? Or some examples?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [nmake: build DLL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/d4e50bbb-feba-439e-9f48-47820480eb81)